# Passing xml via query string to Classic ASP form

Tags: xml, asp-classic, query-string, xmlhttprequest

I have a test form, (see below), that if I Submit manually, (clicking the Submit button), returns an XML list of orders from the action script.

I would like to be able to pass the XML currently contained in the test HTML form programmaticaly via xmlHTTP. So far no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<form action="processorders.asp" method="post" name="Orders" target="_blank">
    <textarea cols="80" rows="10" name="request">
     <REQUEST Version="1.0">
         <RequestID>06012005171718</RequestID>
         <Command>Orders</Command>
         <UserID>myuserID</UserID>
         <Password>xyzuvw</Password>
         <Status>all</Status>
         <SecurityKey></SecurityKey>
         <OrderStartNumber>2255</OrderStartNumber>         
      </REQUEST>
   </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @Eddins So, you want to use your web browser to send the HTTP HTML POST through XML protocolo instead?

Comment: @J Eddins Add some more details on what you are trying to do... you want a web page that auto submits this form? or you would like javascript code that is embedded in a web page that sends this xml asynchronously to the server?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but you could try something like this:

```
Dim objXMLHTTP, returncode, XMLstring
XMLstring =  "<REQUEST Version=""1.0"">"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<RequestID>06012005171718</RequestID>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<Command>Orders</Command>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<UserID>myuserID</UserID>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<Password>xyzuvw</Password>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<Status>all</Status>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<SecurityKey></SecurityKey>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "<OrderStartNumber>2255</OrderStartNumber>"
XMLstring = XMLstring & "</REQUEST>"
' Create an xmlhttp object:
Set objXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
' Or, for version 3.0 of XMLHTTP, use:
' Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
' Open the connection to the remote server:
objXMLHTTPOpen "POST", "http://url.to.your/target", False
objXMLHTTP.Send cstr(XMLstring)
' Actually Sends the request and returns the data:
returncode = objXMLHTTP.responseText
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
' Now do with the returncode what you like (this is the response HTML form the target URL)
```

Please note that:
- you are sending username and password data over an unsecure HTTP line
- the XML is not validated or parsed, you might need to run it through an XML parser

Rico Suave